# Select all rows with equal values in 2 columns within each group

Tags: sql, h2

Consider the following table

```
ID   || YEAR  || TERM  || NAME   || UNIT    
----------------------------------------
1    || 1985  || 1     || MARIE  || 01VS
1    || 1986  || 2     || MARIE  || 01VS
1    || 1986  || 2     || MARIE  || 07GB 
1    || 1986  || 3     || MARIE  || 07GB
2    || 1992  || 1     || AVALON || 01VS
2    || 1992  || 2     || AVALON || 01VS
2    || 1992  || 3     || AVALON || 01VS
3    || 2001  || 1     || DENIS  || 08HK
3    || 2001  || 1     || DENIS  || 07GB
3    || 2001  || 2     || DENIS  || 08HK
3    || 2002  || 1     || DENIS  || 08HK
```

I wanted to write a sql query in H2 which would return all rows for each **ID** in which **YEAR** and **TERM** have equal values. So for the table above the result should be like below:

```
ID   || YEAR  || TERM  || NAME   || UNIT    
----------------------------------------
1    || 1986  || 2     || MARIE  || 01VS
1    || 1986  || 2     || MARIE  || 07GB
3    || 2001  || 1     || DENIS  || 08HK
3    || 2001  || 1     || DENIS  || 07GB
```

Comment: and should someone have 3 records for the same ID, year, term and name that don't match in unit.... Would you want to see 6 records in the results  say A, B, C:  AC, BC, BA, BC, CA, CB?  or just 3?  AB, AC, BC

Comment: Just 3. Like in the example above for ID 1, we have 2 records with same ID, Year, Term and Name but unit  does't match. So the resulting output has only those 2 rows as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 
              from table t1 
              where t1.id = t.id and t1.year = t.year and 
                    t.term = t1.term and t1.unit <> t.unit
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below would work I think

```
select *
from table t
where exists (select id, term from table t2 
where t2.id = t.id 
and t2.term = t.term
group by id, term
having count(*) > 1)
```

However it would be easier if the table had a primary key of some sort.

Comment: What if i create a unique Row ID for each row. Does that help simplify the solution?

Comment: In a way. You could do where exists (select * from table2 t2 where t2.primarykey <> t.primarykey and t2.id =t.id and t2.term = t.id). It's a bit simpler in that you are looking only for records where there is another record in the table with the same values in term and id. The group by and count does that too but is a bit less efficient.

Comment: By the way its TERM and YEAR (not ID?) which I am looking for to be equal. But I get your point. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about joining the table to a subquery with GROUP BY and a HAVING ?

```
select t.*
from yourtable t
join 
(
    select ID, YEAR, TERM
    from yourtable 
    group by ID, YEAR, TERM
    having count(*) > 1
) d on (d.ID = t.ID and d.YEAR = t.YEAR and d.TERM = t.TERM);
```